# postgresql procedure for finding hie parent chain

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I am new to postgresql and need a little help.I have a table named products

```
ID Product Parent_ID
1  laptop   Null
2  Camera   1
3  Iphone   1
4  Mouse    2
5  Printer  2
6  Scanner  3
7  HardDisk 3
```

I want to create a function in postgres to get the hierarchy of the parent chain of any value i pass like if i pass 4 then my output should be

```
id parent_id
1  Null
2  1
4  2
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (You've already got one answer that is product specific. Don't waste people's time writing answers for products not involved.)

Comment: I am using postgres ofcourse (and thank you so much for your reply)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use "recursive with" clause. Kindly check below query.

```
WITH RECURSIVE recursiveTable AS (
SELECT id, parent_id  
FROM table_name
WHERE id = 4  -- you can pass an id here to get the output
UNION ALL
SELECT t.id, t.parent_id
FROM table_name t                  
JOIN recursiveTable rt ON t.id = rt.parent_id 
)
SELECT * FROM recursiveTable
```

You can read more about recursive with clause on it official websites. Or you can check couple of examples.

Here is one link 
http://technobytz.com/recursive-query-evaluation-postgresql.html

Function: Try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_name(param_id INT) 
RETURNS TABLE (
id INT,
parent_id INT
) 
AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY WITH RECURSIVE recursiveTable AS (
SELECT t.id, t.parent_id  
FROM table_name t
WHERE t.id = param_id  -- you can pass an id here to get the output
UNION ALL
SELECT t.id, t.parent_id 
FROM table_name t                  
JOIN recursiveTable rt ON t.id = rt.parent_id
)
SELECT * FROM recursiveTable ;

END; $$ 

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Function Execution:
    select * from function_name(4)

Comment: Thanks Fahad but i am not able to convert it into posgtres function. Can u please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: yeah i am trying in that only but guess it is not working.i hv jz started yesterday on functions

Comment: Could you please replace table_name with your actual table name. and execute it.

Comment: yeah i did it is working really fine but my point is i want to convert this into postgresql function and want to make it generalize like whatever value i pass in the argument it gives me the result accordingly

Comment: create or replace function new(id integer)
returns table(id integer, parent_id integer) as $$
begin
WITH RECURSIVE recursiveTable AS (
SELECT id, parent_id  
FROM employee
WHERE id = 
UNION ALL
SELECT t.id, t.parent_id
FROM employee t                  
JOIN recursiveTable rt ON t.id = rt.parent_id 
)
end;
$$ language plpgsql

Comment: i am trying this query to create the function but it is not working

Comment: You don't need PL/pgSQL for this. A plain SQL function would do just as well

Comment: @naina i have modified function please check and let me know.

Comment: Thank you Fahad for the help :)

Comment: You can mark answer as correct so that someone will take a reference of that.

Comment: It's done..but the output is "(4,2)"
"(2,1)"
"(1,)"
coming in one column i want them in two columns like
id parent_id
4  2

Comment: sorry i didnt get you

Comment: Try calling your function like this. select * from function_name(4).