# Unlimited Category Nesting Using PostgreSQL Query

Tags: php, postgresql, nested, categories

I need some help about Category nesting on PostgreSQL. 
My database table structure like this below image.
I am trying to build Unlimited nested category and subcategory.
So what can I do now?

[image: Table Structure Image]

Comment: Use [Recursive CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-with.html).

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43672913/postgresql-procedure-for-finding-hie-parent-chain/43673289#43673289 Could you please also add exact output which you want?

Comment: Could you please check this ? select id, t. category_name as sub_category , t2.category_name as category
from table_name t 
join table_name t2 on t.id = t2.parent_id 
and parent_id is null 
where parent_id is not null Replace table_name with your actual table. Let me know it helped or not.